# Cloud Functions Permissioning Issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, permission-denied

I created a GCP cloud function in Go runtime 1.13.  All resources are under the same project.

It's reading from a pub-sub topic A doing a transformation on the message writing to a different topic B.

I've had this working on the test project and that worked fine but I can't seem to reproduce it in our production environment.

I bound the function to a service account that is given the Pub/Sub Publisher and Viewer role.

But I seem to keep on getting this error:

```
rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = User not authorized to perform this action.
```

So summarize/clarify, reading from topic A gives no problems but writing to topic B makes the function crash.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try to add a permission as a Pub/Sub Editor: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/1502#issuecomment-421679585

Comment: Split your issue. Where the problem occur? When you are reading? deploying? writing to the other topic? It's not clear where the problem happens

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere It's a cloud function, it deploys in GCP's infrastructure. https://cloud.google.com/functions.

There are two topics. 
Reading from topic1, doing a transformation and writing to topic2.

Comment: @RallyH I tried granting Editor permission and that still doesn't work

Comment: Are the pubsubs in the same project? Did you deploy your cloud function in trigger-http mode or trigger-topic mode?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a user error.  I'm sorry for wasting everyone's time and appreciate all the feedback.  It seems like I was pointing to the wrong project and go figure I didn't have permissions.

Thank you all for the help.